# Copy specific files to another folder

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

Hello I got a question regarding copying files from specific folders towards another one with a batch file.

I have the following code:

```
echo off
set arg1=%1
set "arg2=%~2"
set arg3=%3

FOR /R %arg1% %%G IN (%arg3%) DO (
    COPY %%G %arg2%\tempsrc\%%~nxG
)
```

To the input of the arguments:

```
arg1 = The path where the files are located
arg2 = the output path
arg3 = the file where it should be search for.
```

To run for example the batch file: `test.bat "C:\Batch\SourceDir" "C:'\Batch\Output" "test.xml"`

Within the SourceDir folder I have two sub folders:

- 1000

  - text.xml
- 2000

  - test.xml

In each of this folder the file `test.xml` is located. I want to copy both files to the output dir and the latetst file should overwrite the previous one.

This unfortunately does not work. Can anyone perhaps tell me why? I get the message: ***The system cannot find the file specified.***

Comment: A folder or file with a space will result in an error because it will think it are multiple arguments. If you add quotes between your source and destination on the COPY command, it will likely work. Also, your example has an ' in it. Is that a typo?

Comment: Yep Thanks! That was the trick, thanks for notifying the typo also! @LPChip

Comment: I'll write you an answer so others will know you no longer need help. :)

Comment: yep good idea! @LPChip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A folder or file with a space will result in an error because it will think it are multiple arguments. If you add quotes between your source and destination on the COPY command, it will likely work.

Your script would become:

```
echo off
set arg1=%1
set "arg2=%~2"
set arg3=%3

FOR /R %arg1% %%G IN (%arg3%) DO (
    COPY "%%G" "%arg2%\tempsrc\%%~nxG"
)
```